# Preg_replace or JavaScript .remove to delete an element in a wordpress site?

Tags: php, jquery

Which method is the better approach to remove a very specific div that needs removing?

jQuery's .remove? Or through a preg_replace function before the content loads?

The reason I ask is that because jQuery removes elements after they are created, I thought perhaps in 1 out of 1,000 (random number) jQuery might load slowly and the user would see the element disappear in the first half a second of page loading or whatever.

Or is this assumption completely wrong?

Comment: Neither seem like a good option. What creates the element and why can't you stop it being created in the first place?

Comment: @GeorgeReith is right. Stop it from being created, period.

Comment: And apart from George’s comment – can’t you target that element via CSS selector and hide it using `display:none` in your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer:

The simplest way to remove the element is to target it with a suitable CSS selector and give it `display:none`. Then, barring a FOUC (which would distract the user anyway), the element will not show, even for a fraction of a second.

That being said, it is much more reasonable to just not have the element be generated in the first place. Something in the source must be creating it, so just remove it from the source.